# What is the volume of the intersection of four cylinders of equally radius equally spaced?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry

I saw that question at the certain forum and answered it with help of
Mathematica 13.1 in such a way. The angles between the unit vectors
`{0, 0, 1}, {-Sqrt[2/9], -Sqrt[2/3], -1/3}, {-Sqrt[2/9], Sqrt[2/3], -1/3}` and `{Sqrt[8/9], 0, -1/3}`
are equal because all the pairwise inner products equal `-1/3`.
The first cylinder is defined as `cyl1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];`. The second cylinder
is made from the first one by the rotation around the origin which transforms
`{0, 0, 1}` to `{Sqrt[8/9], 0, -1/3}}`:

```
 cyl2 = TransformedRegion[r1, Function[p, RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, {Sqrt[8/9], 0, -1/3}}] . {p[[1]],  p[[2]], p[[3]]}]]
```

> `ParametricRegion[{{-(x/3) + (2 Sqrt[2] z)/3,  y, -((2 Sqrt[2] x)/3) - z/3}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, y, z}]`

As we see, `cyl2` is  parametrically defined. Next, we find the intersection and volume of these cylinders:

```
intersect1= RegionIntersection[cyl1, cyl2]; Volume[intersect1]
```

> `4 Sqrt[2]`

Now we consider the third cylinder

```
 cyl3 = TransformedRegion[r1, Function[p, RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, {-Sqrt[2/9], Sqrt[2/3], -1/3}}] . {p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}]];
```

and its intersection with `intersect1`

```
intersect2 = RegionIntersection[intersect1, cyl3];
```

and the volume

```
Volume[intersect2]
```

> `4.72311`

We see Mathematica fails to produce an exact result (which is of no need in the most of cases).

At last, the fourth cylinder

```
cyl4 = TransformedRegion[r1,Function[p, RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, {-Sqrt[2/9], -Sqrt[2/3], -1/3}}] . {p[[ 1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}]]
```

, its intersection with the previous ones

```
intersect3 = RegionIntersection[intersect2, cyl4]
```

and the final volume

```
 Volume[intersect3]
```

> `4.54725`

Let us visualize

```
 RegionPlot3D[intersect2, PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}},
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]
and

```
RegionPlot3D[intersect3, PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}},
PlotPoints -> 100, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

Is it possible to obtain an exact result for `Volume[intersect3]` with Mathematica? The symmetry of `intersect3` and
[that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737635/volume-of-the-intersection-of-ten-cylinders?rq=1) encourage.

Edit. Minor typos (unit instead of init, cyl1 instead of r1, cyl2 instead of r2).

Comment: The Inclusion-Exclusion principle seems applicable here.

Comment: @MikeY: Thank you for your interest to the question. Can you elaborate your comment, giving us details?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid). [That article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615957) is free to read online after registration.